# Using Backend Page section in TYPO3 for multiple pages

Tags: layout, typo3, backend

I'm very new to TYPO3, read a couple of blogs online and understood the concepts of Backend layout and templates. My question might be really easy and basic.

I create a Backend layout for my page with `left, right and middle columns` . The pages under this tree also use the same backend layout with three columns.

But, columns `left and right` will remain the same for all the pages, only `middle column` will have different content.

Now I'm adding content to left, right and middle column on every page, which is very time taking.

Can I just add content to `left and right` for one page and overwrite the `middle` column content on every other page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is simple. You need to use the TypoScript property "slide":

```
styles.content.getRight.slide = -1
```

means that TYPO3 walks the rootline until it finds a page where the right column is filled (use getLeft for the left column).

So you might want to have the content for the right and left column on your root page and delete the contents in the subpages.

Please beware of the following caching issue: If you change the contents on your root page, that doesn't mean that the cache of pages inheriting this content are rebuilt. If you want to clear the whole (!) cache when editing the contents on your root page, put

```
TCEMAIN.clearCacheCmd = all
```

to the Page TS Config of the root page. I don't recommend doing this on bigger sites.

There are extensions that help you clear the cache only for a certain branch, e.g. http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sm_clearcachecm and http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/stg_clearcache/2.1.2/view/.

Edit the answer the question in your comment: If you want to use the slide feature for other columns than the default ones, you can copy and modify the content object:

```
lib.contentCol99 < styles.content.get # copies colPos = 0
lib.contentCol99.select.where = colPos=99 # uses the content from col 99
lib.contentCol99.slide = -1 # walk the rootline until content is found
```

Edit 2: When you're using a FLUIDTEMPLATE, you can use the cObject helper use the content:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.contentCol99">
   Lorem ipsum dummy 
</f:cObject>
```

With traditional subparts- and marker-based templating, assign the content to your template, e.g.:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEMPLATE
[...]
page.10.subparts.contentCol99 < lib.contentCol99
```

and use it as a subpart in the template.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much. This did it for me `sidebar < styles.content.getRight
  sidebar.slide = -1`. 

For others: http://wiki.typo3.org/Content_Slide

Comment: Well actually. It does not work if the name of the column is other than `left or right` . What if I have other columns with other names?

Comment: It also does not work if have multiple columns in my BE layout !

Comment: So, how can I use `lib.contentCol99` in my FLUID template? like this `{lib.contentCol99}`. Is this right ?

Answer (score 0):

The `slide` described by **lorenz** is one possibility, other (if you don't want to allow editors to modify the columns) is using TypoScript for filling these columns and hiding them in the BE.

To 'declare' the content on some hidden page and then use it on other pages you need to just use a [`CONTENT`](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.3.1/view/1/7/#id2518969) cObject (where `123` is an `uid` of that hidden page), like:

```
styles.content.getLeft < styles.content.get
styles.content.getLeft {
    select.where = colPos=1
    select.pidInList = 123
}
```

(*note: written from top of my head, testing required*)

To display only desired columns in BE use this snippet in your `PageTS`

- http://www.typo3wizard.com/en/snippets/common-problems-and-solutions/hide-unused-columns-in-the-backend.html

Finally you can mix the approaches - use the slide + hiding columns on subpages, so you can fill it only on the main page and it will be inherited to all levels without possibility of overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

I favour @biesior's solution too. The way I handle repeating content in the backend is different, though:

In your case, BE Layout only needs the middle column for the pages.

Then I would make a sysfolder, "aside". In this sysfolder, I would create a page (or even a sysfolder) for the left cols content and one for the right col.

Now you can pull out all the content of these pages via CONTENT in Typoscript and you're set. Neither sliding nor hiding required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your problem is solved, but if you want to avoid the TypoScript stuff, you can use this extension: [ad: content slider extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/ad_contentslide)

```
This adds a checkbox to inherit content elements. 
Extends default TypoScript object "styles.content.get" for all columns.
```

Check on the content section you want to be inherited and include the extension in the child pages' static template and you're done !

For an example: [click here](http://t3brightside.com/blog/article/simplifying-typo3-showing-content-elements-through-subpages/)